# MVEL expression using programmatic configuratoin in Smooks

Tags: smooks

I did simple java to java transformation with programmatic configuration and it worked well. Now I need to extend it with following use cases, actually all of them depend on MVEL expressions. 
I found examples with Xml configuration, so solution may look as follows:

```
   <jb:expression property="underlying" execOnElement="__und">
        mapper.lookup(__some/_field)
   </jb:expression>
```

But how to do it with **programmatic configuration** (i.e. using [Bean](http://www.milyn.org/javadoc/v1.5/smooks-cartridges/javabean/org/milyn/javabean/Bean.html))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following worked for me (Smooks 1.5):

```
.bindTo("underlying", rmp.newBean(String.class, "__und",
    new MVELFactory<String>("mapping.lookup(__some/_field)")))
```